# Graphiz Dot Vertical Nodes

Tags: graphviz, dot

So I have this,[image: Not-what-I-want]

How do I get rid of this random jog? It works fine from nodes 1 until this point, and then onwards until node 125 (at which point my graph ends currently)

These nodes are on the side to keep the ones in the middle aligned with each other and chronological.

EDIT: Here's the [graphviz file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/grh15j1hveijsgu/APOXZFamilyTree.gv?dl=0) It's my fraternity chapter's family tree.

Comment: Hard to tell without more information... You should provide a graphviz file reproducing the problem.

Comment: I added the file, please take a look. It's a mess I'm working on organizing